# How to make a relative MVC controller/view call within another .jsp page?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a /views/home/index.jsp that has a link to call another page from another controller.

**views/home/index.jsp (`http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/home` <- this controller/method calls "home/index")**

```
<li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home2" target="_blank">home2</a></li>
```

The page home.index needs to redirect to is hosted by home2 controller:

**views/home2/index.jsp (`http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/home2` <- this controller/method calls "home2/index")**

Instead of using:

```
href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home2"
```

How can I just using something relative for the link such as:

```
href="/home2"
```

Comment: just without the slash? so it will resolve the
http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/home2
address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per @Atais:

"just without the slash? so it will resolve the localhost:8080/mywebsite/home2 address "